# Как правильно расставлять операнды при сравнении?

Tags: c++, if, порядок

Часто в коде вижу `if 0 < x` вместо `if x > 0`. Почему так принято писать?

Comment: Обычно это принято для равенства, и смысл в том, что если по ошибке напишешь `if (x=0) ...`, компилятор пропустит, а если `if (0=x) ...` - то нет...

Comment: Так принято писать потому что на любых числовых осях меньшее число находится левее большего, потому `0` левее, а `х` правее в этом сравнении.

Comment: А еще некоторые типы ограничиваются только оператором `<`.

Comment: @Harry, благодарю. Это ответ, который я искал.